# What is the geometric intuition for the basic trigonometric Fourier integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, trigonometry, fourier-analysis

What is the geometric intuition for the trigonometric Fourier integrals?

For example, can someone help me understand the geometry of :

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos^2(x)dx = \pi$ and $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}sin^2(x)dx = \pi$?

Why should the area under these graphs over any interval of length $2\pi$ to be $\pi$?

Also, I'd like to understand the geometetric intuition of the orthogonality of the set of triginometric functions $\{cos(1x),sin(1x),cos(2x),sin(2x),...\}$  wrt to the inner product $(f,g) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)g(x)dx$

i.e.:

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(nx)sin(mx)dx = 0 \text{ for all } m,n$

$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}cos(nx)cos(mx)dx = 0 \text{ when } m \neq n$

What is the geometric understanding of why the areas under these graphs on any interval of length $2\pi$ is zero?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Would you accept product-to-sum identities as a way to interpret these integrands geometrically? If so, I think that leads to an answer.

Comment: ... Otherwise, it is much simpler to undertand orthogonality on complex functions $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{i \pi m t}\overline{e^{i \pi n t}}dt=0$ iff $m \ne n$. In this case, no geometric intuition...

Comment: @runway44 $\cos(x)\sin(y) = \frac{1}{2}[\sin(x+y)+sin(x-y)]$. Okay fine $\sin$ is odd so this vanishes when integrating on $[-\pi,\pi]$. However, $\cos(x)\cos(y)$ and $\sin(x)\sin(y)$ both become sums of $\cos$ functions so I do not see geometrically while these should vanish. ANd also I don't see any intuitive geometric reason why $\frac{1+cos(2x)}{2}$ should vanish (in the case of $\int \cos^2(x)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sine and cosine are fundamentally *components* of the same thing: a circle. A good way to parametrize the circle is the complex exponential $\exp(i\theta)$, and then they are the real and imaginary parts. Thus, an integral like $\int_{-\pi}^\pi \cos\theta\,\mathrm{d}\theta$ can be interpreted as $\mathrm{Re}\int_{-\pi}^\pi\exp(i\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta$. Indeed, if we divide this by $2\pi$, the result is the **average** $x$-coordinate of a point on the unit circle! This, **by symmetry**, should be intuitively true: the circle is not biased to the left or the right. Same for $\sin$ as for $\cos$, but with $y$-coordinates.

On way to formalize this intuition of symmetry is that the result should be unaffected by rotations (since multiplying $\int_{-\pi}^\pi\exp(i\theta)\,\mathrm{d}\theta=\oint_{S^1}z\,\mathrm{d}z$ by a phasor, or unit-magnitude complex number, results in an equivalent integral via change-of-variables). But the only point in the plane unaffected by rotations around the origin is the origin itself (i.e. if $z\ne1$ then $zI=I$ implies $I=0$).

The same idea applies to $\exp(in\theta)$ for any integer $n\ne0$: it just goes around the circle multiple times, either clockwise or counter. By symmetry, we expect its integral to be $0$. Thus we expect its components, the integrals of either $\cos(n\theta)$ or $\sin(n\theta)$, to also wind up being $0$. Except, of course, in the even we go around zero times. Then we get $\sin0=0$ or $\cos0=1$.

How do we interpret $f(m\theta)g(n\theta)$ as a "component" of something for $f,g\in\{\cos,\sin\}$? Well, we know from how complex numbers work that if we would get such products in the real / imaginary components of something like $\exp\!\big(i(\alpha\pm\beta)\big)$. If we write these out and then solve for the products, we get the standard product-to-sum identities with $\frac{1}{2}[f((m+n)\theta\big)\pm g\big((m-n)\theta)]$ for $f,g\in\{\cos,\sin\}$. As I pointed out, the resulting integral of either $f$ or $g$ must be zero, except in the case of $\cos0$ in which case it is the constant that appears in front of $\cos0$ (times the length of the interval of integration).

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of your question: clearly it's not surprising that $\sin(nx)$ and $\cos(nx)$ are orthogonal under the $L^2$ inner product on functions on $[0,2\pi]$, by symmetry of these functions.

It's less obvious why $\sin(nx)$ and $\sin(mx)$ are orthogonal for $n \neq m$. Perhaps it's not geometric in the way you're hoping for, but here's how I see it: $\sin(nx)$ and $\sin(mx)$ are both eigenfunctions of the self-adjoint operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ with different eigenvalues, and so must be orthogonal. In other words, the surface $$\left\langle f, \frac{d^2}{dx^2}f\right\rangle = 1$$
is an "ellipsoid" in the infinite-dimensional metric space of square-integrable functions on $[0,2\pi]$, and  $\sin(nx)$ and $\sin(mx)$ are two of its orthogonal "principal axes."

Comment: Thank you! WIsh I could accept two answers